# Name 'AdobeReader' is not declared vb.net

Tags: vb.net, adobe-reader

I'm  trying to follow a tutorial but I keep getting the warning:

> Name 'AdobeReader' is not declared

Can sombody tell me what is wrong?  The tutorial is found [here](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/open-pdf-file-vbnet-applicatin-124401.aspx), and I'm  trying out Answer 2 from that page, which says:

> Here is another way to read pdfs.
>
> Right click on any of the tabs in your toolbox and click choose
>   items.(Just make sure you have a version of adobe reader installed
>   before starting.) When the dialog box pops up click the 'com
>   components' tab then pick tha 'adobe pdf reader' com component. Click
>   ok and you should now see a 'adobe pdf  reader' control in your
>   toolbox. Click this and drag it to your vb form.(you may need to
>   resize it, usually appears very small). Now in order to read any pdf
>   just alter the 'src' property of the control either in code or in the
>   designer. when you run the program you should be able to view the pdf
>   doc in the vb form with most of the options you get in adobe reader.
>   Here is how you would alter the 'src' property in code.

```
PrivateSub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) HandlesMyBase.Load 
    AdobeReader.src = "C:\mydoc.pdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you successfully place the adobe reader control on your form?  If so, what did you name it?

Comment: Yeah i did sucessfully place the readers control on the form and left its orriginal name which is AxAcroPDF1

Comment: Try changing that line in the code, then, from `AdobeReader.scr = ...` to `AxAcroPDF1.src = ...`  I assume that's supposed to be the control name and the tutorial didn't properly specify that.

Answer (score 2):

If I´m getting your Question right, you just want to open a PDF-File.
Simply call:

```
Process.Start("Path/To/MyPdfFile.pdf")
```

Comment: That would simply launch a separate application to load the PDF.  It wouldn't load it into a control on the form.

Comment: That may be the case, it's hard to say given the way the question is written.  It's not a bad answer, I just thought I should clarify that it would do the same thing, but in a very different way.

Comment: Yeah and i can add it ussing a webbrowser too but this dosnt meet my expectation either (the web browser method is slow)